# jQuery Function Window.height() Change its height when Devices orientation Change

Tags: jquery

I have developed a responsive web page which have a fullwidth background . I have used background in css and used window:height() function to make its height equal to the viewport height

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#wrapper').height($(window).height());
});
```

below is the screenshot of the page

http://prntscr.com/6db3o5

when it open on small devices and after it loads once and when i rotate my device its height remains the same i.e of previous height which actually was when page load first how can i change it wihout loading page again or is there any other way to do it??

thanks

Comment: if you're using jQuery Mobile, perhaps you can use this [orientationchange event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).on('ready resize orientationchange', function(){
    jQuery('#wrapper').height($(window).height());
});
```

The above code will register handlers for all the specified events which is self explanatory. At first `ready` event will be triggered and the handler will calculate layout as required, the screen size changes again only on `resize` or `orientationchange` which are the only situations where we need to calculate and do the layout again. So this code is kind of fail proof in my experience.

Comment: Thanks Sabitth your function worked but the image in the background is placed using background-size:cover; but when i rotate my device back to its previos orintation background-image position chnages do you have any idea why it is happening??

Comment: @AlexChar Sure, I have just added a brief explanation.

Comment: @tayyabrashid Please create a demo in jsfiddle or so as this is some edge case, there is a chance that its some bug in the mobile browser you are using.